# Why is my ASP.NET Button control not calling the appointed function?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-web-developer-2010

I want to set up a search functionality on my web site. The user types some information into a text box and click a search button. Upon clicking the search button, a database is searched using the text in the text box, and the results are displayed in a table. If the text in the text box matches one result from the database perfectly, rather than displaying a list of results the page is populated with detailed information about the matching result.

In order to make it easier to match a result exactly, I want to add a button next to each result which "selects" that result, filling the text box with that result's text and therefore populating the page with the details. Here's what I have.

Upon clicking the search button, after the check to see if a result is matched exactly, I create a table which contains the results and the buttons:

```
for(int x=0; x < res_list.Length; x++)
{
     TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
     TableCell textCell = new TableCell();
     TableCell buttonCell = new TableCell();
     buttonCell.ID = "bc" + x;
     Button cellButton = new Button();
     cellButton.ID = "btn" + x;
     textCell.Text = res_list[x];
     textCell.Attributes.Add("Width","60%");
     cellButton.Text = x.ToString();

     // cellButton.OnClientClick = "NameClick"; This property refers to client-side scripts, which I am not using.
     cellButton.Click += new EventHandler(NameClick);

     buttonCell.Controls.Add(cellButton);
     newRow.Cells.Add(firstCell);
     newRow.Cells.Add(buttonCell);
     myTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

I have tried both the OnClientClick method and the Click method seen above, both of which have yielded the same results.

My NameClick function is as follows:

```
void NameClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button sendButton = (Button)sender;
     int index = Int32.Parse(sendButton.Text);
     SearchTextBox.Text = myTable.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
     return;
}
```

I set up a breakpoint at the beginning of the NameClick function, and when I click one of these buttons it is never reached. Why is this function not being called by my buttons?

EDIT: I want to accomplish this without using JavaScript, if possible.

Comment: what is the code on the page for the button?

Comment: I'm creating the button programmatically, I don't have any code in the page for it. The button is added to a cell which is added to a row which is added to a table which IS coded in the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `cellButton.OnClientClick = "NameClick";`, but do you actually have a `NameClick` function in your javascript? If not, clicking the button will cause a JS error which will probably block the postback.

Other than that, it is advisable to assign explicit ID's to controls which you create programatically. Otherwise the autogenerated ID's may change on postback, which will prevent control events from firing.

Something like the following should work (not tested):

```
myTable.ID = "someid";
for (int x=0; x < res_list.Length; x++)
{
  TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
  newRow.ID = "r" + x;
  TableCell textCell = new TableCell();
  TableCell buttonCell = new TableCell();
  buttonCell.ID = "bc" + x;
  Button cellButton = new Button();
  cellButton.ID = "btn" + x;
  textCell.Text = res_list[x];
  textCell.Attributes.Add("Width","60%");
  cellButton.Text = x.ToString();

  //cellButton.OnClientClick = "NameClick"; // not needed unless you have actual JS for it
  cellButton.Click += new EventHandler(NameClick);

  buttonCell.Controls.Add(cellButton);
  newRow.Cells.Add(firstCell);
  newRow.Cells.Add(buttonCell);
  myTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not using javascript; NameClick refers to the C# function in the question. Is OnClientClick specific to javascript?

Comment: `OnClientClick` is the JS to execute when you click the button. See [Button.OnClientClick Property  on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx).

Comment: So does removing the `cellButton.OnClientClick = "NameClick";` line help?

Comment: instead of cellButton.ID = "btn" + "x"; should be cellButton.ID = "btn" + x;

Comment: Adding the ID lines and using only the cellButton.Click method is still simply refreshing the page rather than calling my NameClick function.

Comment: @Andrew: are you recreating the same control tree on postback? If not, the events won't fire. The controls tree you build exists only during one request. If you want to handle events fired by those controls, you must recreate the controls tree on postback (at least the part of the tree which contains the controls which raise the events; control IDs must be identical on the initial request and on postback).

Comment: Ah, I don't know what that means. How do I recreate the control tree on postback?

Comment: See my answer  below, short and to the point with what you need to do.

Comment: @Andrew: the code which creates the controls and wires the event handlers (the code snipped you posted) must be run also on postback (the postback caused by clicking the `cellButton`). Otherwise, during postback, the controls will no longer exist so they won't raise their events. This is how the controls object model works in ASP.NET.

Comment: _TRULY Understanding Dynamic Controls (Part 4)_ (http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/10/16/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-4_2900_.aspx) might be a worthwhile read (actually the whole series is very useful).

Comment: SO has done something weird with the link above. It should be: `weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/10/16/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-4_2900_.aspx`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. This whole postback process seems ridiculous to me, but I guess that's just the way web programming is. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this problem is very specific to how ASP.NET works (it was intended to mimic Web Forms). You could try MVC for a different web programming experience (be it ASP.NET MVC or something else). Anyway, I am glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`cellButton.OnClientClick` should point to a client-side function, i.e. JavaScript.  Do you have a JS function somewhere?

If the answer is no, then we've found your problem.  You should create one.  It will be helpful to set your `ClientIDMode` property of your dynamically generated controls to `Static` or `Predictable`, so your JS function can easiliy access them.

Do you need assistance with the JS function?

Comment: I've been trying to avoid JavaScript, as the site I'm developing is targeting mobile users and, more specifically, a mobile app I'm developing myself. Knowing as little as I do about JavaScript and web browsers, I was told that Apple's UIWebKit API does not automatically handle JS correctly all the time, so rather than figuring out how to make my app handle JS I'm staying away from it altogether. I hadn't realized that the OnClientClick property was specific to a client-side function.

Answer (score 1):

when you click on the button, the  page start the life cycle again and your control Does not exist in the page you need to create the control again or save it in the viewstate or use control state 
when he call back in the life cycle

in the page life cycle event SaveControlState, loadControlState

if you want to create a javascript click event you need to make sure that the control doesnt call to  server side event  for this in the javascript function you need to return false

Answer (score -2):

you have to add this event in your asp syntax for button.

```
 <asp:Button runat="server " OnClick="ButtonClick"/>
```

Comment: I'm creating the Button in the .aspx.cs file associated with the page. Do I still need to put this piece of code somewhere on the page? If so, where, and why?

Comment: then add a event handler for button